# problem with rendering ajax POST call to populate DIV

Tags: html, ajax, post

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out why when I make an ajax POST call to populate a div - it displays just fine when I make the call from within the same SCRIPT block in the HTML document, but as soon as I move the same call out to a separate .js file as a function, nothing renders in the DIV.

I am sure I am just overlooking something but cannot figure out what ???

the following WORKS (ajax call in same script block)

```
<div id="flow">
</div>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax( "http://localhost:8680/jsdv-status-panel/tsv-multi-version",
            {
                data: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        "some_json":
                                {
                                    "id": 0,
                                    ...
                                }
                    }
                ),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'POST',
                success:  function(data){
                    $("#flow").html(data);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I move the call out to a function in a separate .js file, it displays nothing, even though I can see the Response came back as expected (e.g. Network tab of DevTools looking at the call to the external service I can see the valid HTML or preview)

The following does NOT work (no errors, but nothing displays in the DIV)

```
<div id="flow">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/statusPanelMultiVersion.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        statusPanelMultiVersion('#flow', 
                    {
                        "some_json":
                                {
                                    "id": 0,
                                    ...
                                }
                    }
         );
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

statusPanelMultiVersion.js

```
function statusPanelMultiVersion(_dom_obj, _data_objects) {
     $.ajax( "http://localhost:8680/jsdv-status-panel/tsv-multi-version",
        {
            data: JSON.stringify(_data_objects),
            contentType: 'application/json',                
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data){
                $(_dom_obj).html(data);
            }
        });
};
```

Interestingly, I have a similar function in an external file which does an ajax GET - and it works as expected (the results are rendered in the DIV)

```
function statusPanelLastValue(_dom_obj, _params) {
    $.ajax( "http://localhost:8680/jsdv-status-panel/tsv-last-value" + _params,
        {
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'GET',
            success:  function(data){
                $(_dom_obj).html(data);
            }
        });
};
```

and called like so

```
 statusPanelLastValue("#pool", "?biglongquerystring");
```

I am either not seeing something obvious or not understanding a difference between the function() making a POST call and the inline code. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly ?

Comment: can you add error:  function(data){
                alert(data)
            }  - you are probably getting an error and success never fires. If it goes to error we can debug better.

Comment: One thing... What is the purpose of getting a JSON if you are dumping it on a div? Are you sure your POST is returning a JSON?

Comment: Carlos, I your question prompted me to see the problem ! 

I failed to notice the incorrect dataType and ContentType in the request.

not sure how to give you credit if you did not post an answer though

Answer (score 0):

Carlos's question prompted me to see the problem !

I failed to notice the incorrect dataType and ContentType in the request.

This works now

```
function statusPanelMultiVersion(_dom_obj, _data_objects) {
    $.ajax( "http://localhost:8680/jsdv-status-panel/tsv-multi-version",
        {
            data: JSON.stringify(_data_objects),
            dataType : "html",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend:function(req) {
                $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/assets/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>')
            },
            success:  function(data){
                $(_dom_obj).html(data);
            }
        });
};
```